# android file handling

Tags: android, file

i'm newbie for android dev, now i want explore file handling in android, for example how to write a file (ie. sample.txt) and which location, how to read back it, can this file can be view manually

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official Android developer site has plenty of info - 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html